# Java NullPointerException - setting string parameter from text box

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to set a parameter in my Volley request, and I'm not getting and setting the parameter from my input field (in a dialog box) correctly - resulting in a null-pointer. Server side confirms that the parameter is blank. Here's my listDialog method:

```
public void listDialog() {
    // get layout for prompt
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_name_prompt,  null);

final EditText input = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

listName = (input.getText().toString());

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

//set promptview to be the layout file for alerdialog builder
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

// setup a dialog window
alertDialogBuilder
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        EditText listNameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        listName = listNameBox.getText().toString();

            createListRequest();
        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertD.show();
}
```

I set `listName` at the top of my Activity:

```
private String listName;
```

In the `createListRequest` method is where I use the parameter like so:

public void createListRequest() {

```
JsonObjectRequest createRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, createUrl, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                //success
                if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //not success
                Log.d("Error.Response", e.toString());
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error.response", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type",  "application/json");
        headers.put("auth_token", mPreferences.getString("AuthToken", "") );
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", listName);

        return params;
    }
};
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(createRequest);
}
```

I'll be the first to admit that I don't understand Java variables and class fields as well as I should - and this is probably a symptom of that.

Comment: where have you got `NPE`???

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `listNameBox`  is null,because your dialog view is `promptView` and `userInput` id is part of `promptView`,so change

```
    EditText listNameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
```

to

```
    EditText listNameBox = (EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 22 you forgot class name of *findViewById*. Like line 7 :

```
promptView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you are using findViewbyId instead of use alertD.findViewById then it will work

setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

```
    EditText listNameBox = (EditText) alertD.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    listName = listNameBox.getText().toString();

        createListRequest();
    }
})
```